# How to bind "v-model" property in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want to show list of inputs dynamically.

I am not asking about using v-bind OR v-model, I want to bind v-model property itself (like v-bind:v-model).

Here is the code but it does not work.

```
<template>
  <div class="form-outside">
    <form>
      <div v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
        <div class="caption">{{input.caption}}</div>
        <input :type="input.type" :v-model="input.model" />
      </div>
      <div v-if="error" class="error-message">{{error}}</div>
      <div v-if="kind=='login'" class="suggestion">
        Don't have an account? 
        <nuxt-link to="/signup">Sign up</nuxt-link> instead!
      </div>
      <div v-if="kind=='signup'" class="suggestion">
        Have an account? 
        <nuxt-link to="/login">Log in</nuxt-link> instead!
      </div>
      <div v-if="loading" class="loading">Loading</div>
      <button @click.prevent="submitted" v-if="!loading">{{button_text}}</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AuthForm",
  props: ["kind", "error", "loading"],
  methods: {
    submitted() {
      this.$emit("submitted", {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        confirm_password: this.confirm_password,
        full_name: this.full_name,
        login: this.login,
        username: this.username
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    button_text() {
      if (this.kind == "login") return "Log in";
      if (this.kind == "signup") return "Sign up";
    },
    inputs() {
      return this.possible_inputs.filter(
        input => input.when == "always" || input.when == this.kind
      );
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirm_password: "",
      full_name: "",
      login: "",
      username: "",
      possible_inputs: [
        {
          caption: "Full Name",
          type: "text",
          when: "signup",
          model: this.full_name
        },
        {
          caption: "Email",
          type: "email",
          when: "signup",
          model: this.email
        },
        {
          caption: "Email or Username",
          type: "text",
          when: "login",
          model: this.login
        },
        {
          caption: "Username",
          type: "text",
          when: "signup",
          model: this.username
        },
        {
          caption: "Password",
          type: "password",
          when: "always",
          model: this.password
        },
        {
          caption: "Confirm Password",
          type: "password",
          when: "signup",
          model: this.confirm_password
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

(This is some additional text because stackoverflow says “It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details”, just ignore it)

Answer (score 0):

In `data(){}` you cannot assign in this way `model: this.email` so you need to assign it in `mounted() {}` hook, check the code below:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirm_password: "",
      full_name: "",
      login: "",
      username: "",
      possible_inputs: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.possible_inputs = [
      {
        caption: "Full Name",
        type: "text",
        when: "signup",
        model: this.full_name
      }, {
        caption: "Email",
        type: "email",
        when: "signup",
        model: this.email
      }, {
        caption: "Email or Username",
        type: "text",
        when: "login",
        model: this.login
      }, {
        caption: "Username",
        type: "text",
        when: "signup",
        model: this.username
      }, {
        caption: "Password",
        type: "password",
        when: "always",
        model: this.password
      }, {
        caption: "Confirm Password",
        type: "password",
        when: "signup",
        model: this.confirm_password
      },
    ];
  },
};
</script>
```